# Set last 4 bits to 0

Tags: c#, .net, bit-manipulation

I want to set the last 4 bits of my byte list to 0. I've tried this line of code but it does not work:

myData = 1111.1111
myData should be = 1111.0000

```
(myData & 0x0F) >> 4
```

Comment: There is a BitArray class within .net, may be this could help. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.bitarray?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: You are not clear about 'byte list' or about what you do withthe result. And `11111111` is a bad test pattern.

Comment: What is the type of `myData`? `byte`? `long`? `int`?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean that "4 last bits" is 4 least significant bits, I have this code example for you:

```cs
var myData = 0xFF;
var result = myData & ~0xF;
```

So, basically, what you want here is not to set the 4 least significant bits to 0, but to preserve the rest of the data. To achieve this you have to prepare the "passthrough" mask, which matches the criteria, this is the one's complement of the non-needed bits mask i.e. the one's complement of the `0xF` (also note that 0xF = (2 to the power of 4) - 1 -- where 4 is the number of the desired cleared out LSBs). Thus, `~0xF` is the desired mask -- you just have to apply it to the number -- `myData & ~0xF`.

N.B. The one's complement approach is better than `magical numbers`, pre-computed yourself (such as `0xF` in the anwser above), as the compiler will generate the valid number of MSBs (most significant bits) for the type you use this approach against.

#### An even safer approach would be to compute the one's complement of the variable itself, giving the effective code stated below:

```cs
var myData = 0xFF;
var result = ~(~myData | 0xF);
```

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

To preserve the 4 high bits and zero the 4 low bits

`myData & 0xF0`